# Как получить список подписчиков Youtube?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Можно ли определить подписан пользователь на определенный канал? В доках Youtube API v3 постоянно ругается на права. Если это единственный способ, который позволяет получить список подписчиков, то где брать `{YOUR_API_KEY}`?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#try-it

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&mine=true&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D

По такому URL не могу получить данные.

Answer (score 2):

В [документации](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) чёрным по белому сказано:

> ### Before you start
>
> 1. You need a [Google Account](https://www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount) to access the Google Developers Console, request an API key, and register your application.
> 2. [Register your application](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) with Google so that it can submit API requests.
> 3. After registering your application, select the YouTube Data API as one of the services that your application uses:
>
>    1. Go to the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and select the project that you just registered.
>    2. In the sidebar on the left, expand **APIs & auth**. Next, click **APIs**. In the list of APIs, make sure the status is **ON** for the **YouTube Data API v3**.
> 4. Familiarize yourself with the core concepts of the JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) data format. JSON is a common, language-independent data format that provides a simple text representation of arbitrary data structures. For more information, see json.org.

Ключ API — это ключ, который уникально идентифицирует ваше приложение. Каждому приложению выдаётся свой ключ, и на этот ключ накладываются ограничения, сколько можно делать запросов, как часто, куда и т.п. `{YOUR_API_KEY}` — это плейсхолдер, куда надо вставить ключ своего приложения. Для этого [приложение нужно зарегистрировать](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application). Ну а дальше смотрите пункт 3 и нажимайте всё по порядку, как указано.